# C#, Method creates a list but is not of type list?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, type-hinting, splist

Coming from PHP I am not use to assigning or returning specific types because PHP really doesn't care. But Coming back to the world of Java and C# these languages do care, when you say pass me this type it expects that type. So what am I do doing wrong and how can I create this to be of type **SPList**

I have a very basic function such as:

```
    protected void createNewList(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        Dictionary<string, List<AddParams>> param = new Dictionary<string, List<AddParams>>();

        // Create the keys
        param.Add("Name", new List<AddParams>());
        param.Add("Type", new List<AddParams>());
        param.Add("Description", new List<AddParams>());

        // Set the values
        param["Name"].Add(new AddParams { type = SPFieldType.Text, required = true });
        param["Type"].Add(new AddParams { type = SPFieldType.Text, required = true });
        param["Description"].Add(new AddParams { type = SPFieldType.Text, required = true });

        // Create the really simple List.
        new SPAPI.Lists.Create(properties, param, "Fake List", "Sample Description", SPListTemplateType.GenericList, "Sample View Description");
    }
```

This will create you a List, a SharePoint 2010 list upon activation of the web part. the name is Fake List and we see we pass in some collumns with their respected parameters. Lets look at this `SPAPI.Lists.Create` method:

```
    public Create(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties, Dictionary<string, List<AddParams>> columns, 
        string name, string description, SPListTemplateType type, string viewDescription)
    {

        SPSite siteCollection = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;
        if (siteCollection != null)
        {
            SPWeb web = siteCollection.RootWeb;
            Guid Listid = web.Lists.Add(name, description, type);
            web.Update();

            // Add the new list and the new content.
            SPList spList = web.Lists[name];
            foreach(KeyValuePair<string, List<AddParams>> col in columns){
                spList.Fields.Add(col.Key, col.Value[0].type, col.Value[0].required);
            }

            spList.Update();

            //Create the view? - Possibly remove me.
            System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection stringCollection =
                new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection();

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<AddParams>> col in columns)
            {
                stringCollection.Add(col.Key);
            }

            //Add the list.
            spList.Views.Add(viewDescription, stringCollection, @"", 100,
                true, true, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPViewCollection.SPViewType.Html, false);
            spList.Update();
        }
    }
```

We can see here that all were doing is creating a SPList object for use in Sharepoint. Upon deployment we have a new list we can add to our pages. So whats the problem?

Well in Php I could pass the `createNewList(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)` to a function requesting the object of type SPList and it would work (unless im missing something >.>) Here its like, no that's not a SPList go away.

So My question is:

**What do I have to change so that I can both create the list and return the SPLIst object?** is it as simple as `return new SPAPI.Lists.Create(properties, param, "Fake List", "Sample Description", SPListTemplateType.GenericList, "Sample View Description");`

Because that seems right to me.

**Update**

Turning the method signature to SPList and returning the `return new ....` did not work.

Comment: You appear to be calling a *constructor* of a class called `Create`. That doesn't seem like a good idea. It's far from clear what you're really trying to do here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return an SPList from both your methods:

```
protected SPList createNewList(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
    //Do the stuff

    SPList result = new SPAPI.Lists.Create(properties, param, "Fake List", "Sample Description", SPListTemplateType.GenericList, "Sample View Description");
    return result;
}

public SPList Create(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties, Dictionary<string, List<AddParams>> columns, 
    string name, string description, SPListTemplateType type, string viewDescription)
{
    // Do the stuff

    return spList;
}
```